# Copying a PostgreSQL table to GitHub

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Using the Heroku CLI and following [these instructions](https://jamesbedont.com/export-a-heroku-postgres-table-to-a-csv-file), I am trying to save the DB tables as CSVs.

I can see the tables on the CLI and when I use the copy command I see:

```
baer-faxt-prod::DATABASE-> \COPY artists TO 'artists_export.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',',  HEADER true);
COPY 1010
```

It seems to have been successful, but I don't see it on GitHub.

I know very little about using this CLI and Heroku in general. Someone had set this up for us a while back and we need to move the DB.

If not GitHub, where does the file go?

Comment: "I am trying to save the DB tables as CSVs into the git"—why? Normally data should not be committed to version control.

Comment: Maybe she's talking about the "GitLab artifact repository" that is similar to a Docker registry or Maven artifact repository.

Comment: @TheImpaler, we shouldn't have to guess. OP needs to clarify.

Comment: @Chris To clarify - I'm trying to download all tables in the DB to move it to a new DB on another server. Getting the data into a CSV is necessary for me, to create a new CSV template for eventual upload into the new DB. I apologize - I didn't think the why was necessary. I just do not know another way to do it. There is no command to download, so sending it to the Git would enable me to download it from there.

Comment: Okay, but why should that data end up in your repository? You should be able to dump it, then load it, without committing it, right?

Comment: The OP didn't clarify what "the git" is. Voting to close.

Comment: @chris That's the goal. I need to store it somewhere in an accessible place where I can download it locally and then remove it from that git.  The git being the directory of files my heroku app is attached to.

Comment: Do you just mean the directory where your files are? You don't intend to commit this data to your repository, you just want it on your local machine temporarily?

Comment: @chris Yes, I should have explained it better. When I copy the table, I had been assuming it is saving to the git, now I think it's going elsewhere - I have no idea where the file is saving to so that I can download the csv. It's not in the attached Git.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "the git". "A git" isn't a thing. Do you mean a local repository? Or working directory? A repository on GitHub or similar? The file should be in whatever directory you were in when you ran the command.

Comment: @chris Oh yes, I'm sorry! It is a repository on Github.

Comment: @chris When I ran the command, I was in Heroku's database.  I have no idea where that csv is saving to. I can create backups that show up in Heroku but I can't convert them to csv.

Comment: @RebeccaSkaneCarter, are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: @Chris  I was able to proceed in a different direction. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly won't end up on GitHub. Heroku's GitHub integration works in one direction only: from GitHub to Heroku. It is used for *deployment*, not for bidirectional syncing.

[The PostgreSQL `\COPY` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) doesn't know anything about Git. When used in the format you show above:

```
\COPY artists TO 'artists_export.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',',  HEADER true);
```

it saves to a file called `artists_export.csv` in whatever directory you are in on your local machine when you run the command.

That might be something like `C:\Users\Rebecca\` if you're on Windows, `/Users/Rebecca/` if you're on macOS, `/home/rebecca/` if you're on Linux. Or, it could be your project directory, for example if you did something like `cd some/project/directory/` before connecting to your database.

Disconnect from Postgres, e.g. by typing

```
\quit
```

and then look in whatever directory you're in for a file called `artists_export.csv`.